# Why is Window.Open printing out html rather than rendering it?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-11

helpWindow = Window.Open(“”, “”, configSettings);

helpWindow.location.href = “/eci/resources/help/CBHelp.html”;

This is printing the html rather than rendering it in internet explorer.

Works in chrome, Firefox, etc.

Any idea how I can fix this so that it renders the page rather than printing the html?

Comment: please edit the question and show the href value

Comment: Use the editor toolbar to format your code. Also, please edit your title to ask a question, and don't put tags alongside the title.

Comment: Don' t use `window.open`? Just open that url as a new tab using a real link (but activated via JS), why break the browser's ability to manage history and navigation by resorting to the legacy `open` function?

Comment: Can you please inform us how did you determine that the page is printing instead of rendering? Can you please provide detailed steps to reproduce the issue? If possible you can also share the image of the result you get in IE and other browsers. It can help us to understand the issue in a better way. Thanks for your understanding.